# jquery button clicks doesnt return the result as expected

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following code in jquery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#button1").click(function() {
        alert(1)
        var div = $("div");
        div.animate({
          left: '100px'
        }, "slow");
        div.animate({
          fontSize: '3em'
        }, "slow");
      });

      $("button").click(function() {
        alert(3)
        var div = $("div");
        div.animate({
          left: '50px'
        }, "slow");
        div.animate({
          fontSize: '7em'
        }, "slow");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button2">Start Animation2</button>
  <button id="button1">Start Animation</button>
  <p>By default, all HTML elements have a static position, and cannot be moved. To manipulate the position, remember to first set the CSS position property of the element to relative, fixed, or absolute!</p>
  <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:200px;position:absolute;">HELLO</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i run the code, the start animation2 button runs for the first time but no effect for the second and after clicks. But

> start animation

button works on each click. I can understand it is because i have wrote $("#button1").click(function() for the particular button. But what is the reason for that have no effect on

> start animation2

multiple clicks?

Comment: var div = $("div"); will select all div elements and return an array of the same. See if making it more specific (add a class or say div[0].animate instead of div.animate) solves the problem.

Comment: What effect are you trying to generate? You seem to be confused how the selectors work.

Comment: @KilianStinson animation effect

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the selectors. You've attached events to `#button1` and `button`. Therefore when `#button1` is clicked **both** event handlers run. When `#button2` is clicked **only** the event handler bound to `button` runs. This appears to do nothing because the ending state of `#button1` puts everything in the same position - hence there is nothing to be moved.

Comment: why on second click the div not applying left:50px w.r.to the current position?

Comment: It's because you set the position to 50px. If you want to increment 50px on each click use `left: '+=50px'`

Comment: Ok. But how the browser will consider let:50px from the current position or from initial position?

Comment: Current position.

Comment: So if it considers left:50px from the current position, it should move 50px to left every time right?

Comment: That's right. Although remember you're setting `left: 100px` in the other handler. At this point it would probably be easier if you edited the question so you told us exactly what behaviour you want as this seems a little convoluted at the moment

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
div.animate({
    left: '100px'
}, "slow");`
```

will **SET** your `left` property to `100px` and not **increment** it. It will set it once, and then the second once nothing will change since it's at `100px` already.